# Topology in cosmology

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, differential-geometry, symmetry, topology

Usually in cosmology, we make the hypothesis that the universe is isotropic.

Which conditions does this hypothesis impose on the topology of the universe? Does it fix completely the topology? Are all the *exotic* topologies ruled out?

Comment: I assume OP means exotic topology in the sense of something non-trivial, like the 3-torus. I.e. concerned with global properties. (As far as I'm aware, these aren't ruled out and I don't think they ever can be, we can only make local measurements and determine local properties).

Comment: @mattiav27 the question seemed clear to me, but you could perhaps edit this into the question to get the answer you're looking for. Also note that locally isotropic (just in our patch) vs globally isotropic probably constrains different topologies.

Answer (score 6):

[A relatively recent review by Jean-Pierre Luminet](https://arxiv.org/abs/1601.03884) discusses this subject at some length.  Broadly, it can be summarized as follows:

- The requirements of homogeneity and (local) isotropy do not necessarily mean that the spatial slices of the cosmos are diffeomorphic to $S^3$, $\mathbb{R}^3$, or $H^3$;  these are merely the simplest examples of spaces with positive, zero, or negative uniform curvature.
- In particular, these three spaces are the *universal covering spaces* for any homogeneous and (locally) isotropic space of constant curvature.  All other spaces with these properties can be obtained by "identifying" one of the universal covering space with itself in a particular way.  For example, to get the 3-torus from $\mathbb{R}^3$, you "identify" all points $(x,y,z)$ with the points $(x + a,y,z)$, and similarly for the $y$- and $z$-directions.

- A corollary of this is that local measurements of the spatial curvature scale cannot, in themselves, rule out any particular topology.  The geometric curvature of the universal covering space and that of the topologically "interesting" space are the same under the identification.

Luminet also discusses the tactics that have been used to experimentally search for non-trivial cosmological topology.  It is not impossible to detect this structure from here on Earth, but it effectively requires the Universe to be "small enough" so that light from a given source can reach you from multiple directions.  If your observations come up empty, you may be able to place a lower bound on the size of the Universe, and this may be sufficient to rule out some types of topology (since the volumes of such spaces are related to their curvature scale.)  But in general you can't rule out non-trivial topology entirely, particularly in the case of flat geometries for which the volume of the Universe is effectively arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

I think the question you ask is quite important.
"Which conditions does this hypothesis (isotropy) impose on the topology of the universe?"

I have seen a lot of discussion about various conclusions that something like a 3-torus (or some other topology) cannot be (or has not been) proved to be impossible. It seems to me that it would be very useful for discussions of the non-impossibility to distinguish between (a) some speculative kind of universe is not known to be impossible, and (b) some kind of universe can be shown to have a positive (i.e, definitely greater than zero) probability that it might exist.

It does seem obvious that the (a) type speculations are impossible to confirm to be part of our universe since such things are not possible to have observable evidence supporting their existence in the observable universe.

I have looked for such (b) type statements, but I have never found any.

Comment: How would you propose assigning probabilities to possible topologies for the universe?

Comment: I may be wrong, but do not thnk it is possible. That is the reason I suggest presentations include a clear (a) type statement. Otherwise a naive reader is likely to confuse the usual speculative statement with observation based science.

Comment: The point is that if we can't say something we know to be correct about global topologies, we shouldn't say anything concrete at all. We cannot assign probabilities to something that local measurements cannot determine, so trying to do so is wrong. Unless you can give a physical argument why certain topologies aren't possible, or even just why they're less likely, one shouldn't make such strong claims at all.  So just because some topologies (e.g. Euclidean) is "nicer/simpler" than some other topology, this isn't evidence for what actually exists.

Comment: In other words, all we can and should say is "models X, Y and Z are in agreement with observation/evidence". Anything else becomes more aesthetic than scientific.

Comment: I would be very interested how you differentiate between (a) a speculative universe which is in agreement with all evidence, and (b) the real physical universe. Returning to topologies, something non-trivial has more 'mathematical baggage' (in some sense), but nobodies advocating it to be the accepted model, just that we can't rule it out (so shouldn't). You tagged me in a comment on my other answer, where I said non-trivial topologies are possible even with isotropy, to look at your answer here. But it still seems as if this is the case.

Comment: (a) includes regions ouside of the OU which are asumed to be different from what is observed inside the OU, with no observable evidence supporting the outside differences. I make no claim regarding (b) providing evidence about what is outside the OU, BUT a nodel does give a detaiIed desciption of a conceptual universe with properties both in and out of the OU with observations matching the inside OU part of the model.

Comment: I do not claim that people advocate the non-trivial topologies as observationally supported. What I see to be missing are such speculations not clearly saying there are no models and no observational support.

Comment: @Buzz in your definition for (a) you're smuggling in the assumption that the local geometry should also be the same as the global topology, which we have no evidence for. All we should be able to say is which different models fit observation, and this is all I'm doing. There is no observational support for pinning down **any** global topology *except those consistent with the local geometry*. This means any topologies consistent with local isotropy (in the case of OP's question), and anything more is an assumption (not based on evidence). This is what Michael Seifert's answer also says.

Comment: @Eletie I do not see my discussion as saying "global  geometry should also be the same as the local geometry". I am saying that MODELs say this about the conclusions of the math, GR and/or Friedmann equations. In the absence of making clear that no models exist for a non-trivial topology, it is not clear to a reader whether there is any cosmological distinction between the kind of support that exists between the two kinds of stories, trivial and non-trivial.

Comment: @Buzz you explicitly said that one shouldn't assume regions out side the OU to be different from inside the OU. But you are assuming the opposite, that the local *geometry* should be the same as the global topology. I'm making neither assumption, just sticking to the evidence. I'm not sure if you're familiar with the math but the standard cosmological models are *the same with any acceptable topology*, that is all - this has been known since the 70s. I don't know why you keep saying there are no models for non-trivial topology, when there are plenty of papers.

Comment: @Eletie I could not find where I said:  "one shouldn't assume regions out side the OU to be different from inside the OU."  Please quote the text where I said this. I did a search on (a) "one shouldn't assume", and (b1)  "out side the OU", or (b2) outside the OU", or (c) "different from inside the OU".

Comment: @Buzz I was not quoting verbatim, but I can: You said, regarding defining a universe being speculative, it "includes regions ouside of the OU which are asumed to be different from what is observed inside the OU, with no observable evidence supporting the outside differences." I grant that you didn't say that one *shouldn't* make this type of assumption, but only that it leads to speculative models of the universe. Apologies if I mischaracterised what you said. Hopefully though it's clear that I see all models as equally speculative until there's sufficient evidence for them.

Comment: @Eletie I think I am now understanding you comment. The distinction that I have tried to make is that a reader should be able to understand whether or not a speculation has ANY observable support. If there is NO model, then there is no observable support. If there IS a model,then there is some (albeit perhaps small) support from the general equations which describe properties of the whole universe based on fitting the observable data from the OU. Also, the model specifies assumptions like homogeneity and isometry. From my viewpoint, the math of the model supports some degree of extrapolation.

Comment: I might be mistaken, but over time the accelerating expanding model can calculate what is happening to the matter which previously was inside the OU, but is now outside the OU.

Comment: @Buzz I think on this point we just won't agree. I don't see any more or any less observational support for assuming one topology over another, all we can do is rule out what local isotropy & homogeneity demands to be ruled out. From the literature I've read, the only reason one would consider say $\mathbb{R}^3$ over $\mathbb{T}^3$, is that the former is more 'natural'. But this isn't a physical reason. If you find literature which says otherwise I'd be keen to read it.