# Coordinate Charts to Describe the Universe

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, differential-geometry, universe, topology

This is a bit of a soft question. I'm currently taking a GR course. The professor has asserted that, because the universe has curvature, one needs to cover it by more than one smooth coordinate chart. However, there are manifolds that have nonzero curvature (for example graph manifolds) that can be covered with a single coordinate chart. My question is:
Is it known that the universe cannot be covered with a single coordinate chart?

As far as I know, not much is known about the global topology of the universe (for example, whether or not the universe is compact), so it strikes me as unlikely that we know enough about its global structure to draw a conclusion about how many coordinate charts are necessary, but perhaps there is compelling evidence. I appreciate any thoughts you have on this!

Comment: Related (and links therein may answer your question):  [Topology in cosmology](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/621393/)